# Python - API request works in __init__ but not in function

Tags: python, api, tkinter

im implementing `api requests` to my tkinter app. At the `Gui Class init` there is one `api request` running that works without problems. But when im calling a `function` inside the `class` that is running the same `api request` im getting back an `error`.

I'm not quite sure if it is the `API` or maybe my `class structure`.

My folder structure looks like this

```
Project Folder/
api/
    __init__.py
    api.py
gui/
    __init__.py
    gui.py
main.py
```

The `main.py` holds the `Gui Class` with the `mainloop`.

```
from gui.gui import Gui


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = Gui()
    app.mainloop()
```

The `GUI class` contains the tkinter app and is inherited from `customtkinter.CTk`. Simplified it looks like that

```
import logging

import PIL.Image
from tkinter import *
import tkinter.messagebox
import customtkinter

from api.api import WikiApi


class Gui(customtkinter.CTk):
def __init__(self):
    super().__init__()

    # API
    self.api = WikiApi()
    self.book_list = self.api.get_all_books_from_shelv()['books'] # Fetching all book names from api

    # API Output looks like this
    '''
    {
        'books': [{
                'id': 37,
                'name': 'book-1',
                'slug': 'book-1',
                'description': '',
                'created_at': '2023-04-11T09:16:19.000000Z',
                'updated_at': '2023-04-14T08:40:49.000000Z',
                'created_by': 16,
                'updated_by': 4,
                'owned_by': 16
            }, {
                'id': 38,
                'name': 'book-2',
                'slug': 'book-2',
                'description': '',
                'created_at': '2023-04-13T07:07:23.000000Z',
                'updated_at': '2023-04-13T07:07:23.000000Z',
                'created_by': 16,
                'updated_by': 16,
                'owned_by': 16
            }
        ]
    }
    '''

    # logger
    # screen constants
    # root window attributes & widgets

    # refresh button that calls self.refresh_book_list

def refresh_book_list(self):
    self.book_list.clear()
    self.book_list = [book['name'] for book in self.api.get_all_books_from_shelv()['books']]
    # API response from function
    '''
    {
        'error': {
            'code': 403,
            'message': 'The owner of the used API token does not have permission to make API calls'
        }
    }
    '''
```

The `api.py` contains the class `WikiApi` and simplified looks like this

```
import requests
import logging
import json


class WikiApi:
    def __init__(self):
        self.TOKEN_ID = 'abcdef123'
        self.TOKEN_SECRET = 'password'

        self.HEADER = {
            "Authorization": f"Token {self.TOKEN_ID}:{self.TOKEN_SECRET}",
            "Accept": "application/vnd.api+json"
        }

        self.session = requests.session()
        self.session.headers = self.HEADER
        
    def _get(self, url):
        
        response = self.session.get(url)
        return response.json()
    
    
    def get_all_books_from_shelv(self):
        url = f'url to api endpoint'
        response = self._get(url)
        return response
```

Comment: Hard to diagnose since you've not pasted example of `main()` that makes the two different calls nor the error output. Whatever the root issue is, it appears like the request only works once per `requests.session()`.

Comment: I've added the `main.py`. Its probably not the `requests.session()` because i can make multiple api calls in the `__init__` and they all work, but not in the `function` later on

Comment: Update: I changed the `api class` from `session` to simply `requests.get()`. And it works, but im still not understanding why `session()` wont

Comment: In that case, I think I should post my comment as an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like (and you've seemingly confirmed) that the issue has to do with state retained in the `requests.session()` between the two API calls.

To get more precise details about *precisely* why involves diving into the `requests.session()` implementation or docs for details.

IIRC, `requests` has an extra-verbose way of "logging prepared requests" that can help you at this point.